# To color the react FullCalendar table cells based on past and future times

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am working on a project that utilizes React FullCalendar, and I want to customize the appearance of the table cells based on whether they represent past or future times. Essentially, I want to dynamically colorize the cells to provide visual cues for past, present, and future events.

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {
  calendarRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
   //
 
  }

  eventContent = (arg) => {
    const eventDate = new Date(arg.event.start);

    if (eventDate < new Date()) {
      return { classNames: 'past-event' };
    } else {
      return { classNames: 'future-event' };
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FullCalendar
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
        initialView="dayGridMonth"
        events={[]}
        eventContent={this.eventContent}
        ref={this.calendarRef}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Calendar;
```

css

```
.past-event .fc td {
  background-color: gray;
}

.future-event .fc td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

I want to make like this picture[image]

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
const handleDatesSet = (arg) => {
      if (arg && arg.view && arg.start) {


        const now = new Date();
        const currentView = arg.view;
        const currentDate = arg.start;

        const eventCurrentDate = currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
          weekday: 'short',
          month: 'short',
          day: 'numeric',
          year: 'numeric'
        }).replace(',', '');

        const nowDate = now.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
          weekday: 'short',
          month: 'short',
          day: 'numeric',
          year: 'numeric'
        }).replace(',', '');

        const date1 = new Date(eventCurrentDate);
        const date2 = new Date(nowDate);

        const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.fc tr');
        rows.forEach(row => {
          const tdElements = row.querySelectorAll('td');
          if (tdElements.length > 1) {
            const secondTd = tdElements[1]; // Select the second <td> element

            const dataTimeValue = secondTd.getAttribute('data-time');
            const now = new Date();
            const hours = now.getHours();
            const minutes = now.getMinutes();
            const seconds = now.getSeconds();

            const currentTime = new Date(0, 0, 0, hours, minutes, seconds);

            if (dataTimeValue && dataTimeValue.includes(':')) {
              const [eventHours, eventMinutes, eventSeconds] = dataTimeValue.split(':');
              const eventDataTime = new Date(0, 0, 0, eventHours, eventMinutes, eventSeconds);

              if (date1.getTime() === date2.getTime()) {
                console.log('Today');
                if (eventDataTime.getTime() < currentTime.getTime()) {
                  secondTd.classList.add('past-event');
                  secondTd.classList.remove('future-event');
                  // console.log('Past-Gray');
                } else {
                  secondTd.classList.add('future-event');
                  secondTd.classList.remove('past-event');
                  // console.log('Future-Yellow');
                }
              } else if (date1.getTime() < date2.getTime()) {
                console.log('Past');
                secondTd.classList.add('past-event');
                secondTd.classList.remove('future-event');
              } else {
                console.log('Future');
                secondTd.classList.add('future-event');
                secondTd.classList.remove('past-event');
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }

    };

    // Run the handleDatesSet function every second (1000 milliseconds)
    setInterval(handleDatesSet, 1000);```


\\css
```.past-event {
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
}

.future-event {
  background-color: #dddd99;
}```
````